# 1960s YA novel set in ancient Rome

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, young-adult

Do you remember a YA novel circa 1960s in which the protagonist goes to ancient Rome and when another character gives the "Friends, Romans, Countrymen" speech, he catapults a load of ass's ears into the crowd of listeners?

Comment: Was the protagonist an adult? A kid? Teenager?

Comment: The protagonist was an adult ---- a scientist, I think.